# Local static variables for each thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static

Lets say I have a class that after initialization creates a thread and runs a method in it, within it declares a static variable:

```
void method()
{
     static int var = 0;
     var++;
}
```

If I create more objects of the class, for example 3, then the method will be called 3 times in 3 different threads. After that `var` will equal 3.
How to accomplish the functionality, where each thread has its own static `var` that is independent of others. I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Why not use member variable ?

Comment: Because the needed variable is significant only for the scope of this method and not used anywhere else. For now I have used a member variable, but I am wondering either this wouldn't be better. The method is called periodically and the static var shouldnt change.

Comment: Really? This sounds like you should really use a `local variable` not static, no member, just a local variable in the method-block!!! - Thread-locals like mentioned in the other answers can lead to a bunch of problems with memory leaks and similar in big applications, so should only be used when really necessary!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the `thread_local` keyword which indicates that the object has a thread storage duration. You can use it like that :

```
static thread_local int V;
```

If you want more information about storage class specifiers, you can check [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: And in case your compiler does not support it yet, check out Boost's [thread_local_storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html), which does basically the same, but as a library.

Comment: I am using c++11 so its ok.

Answer (score 15):

This is what the `thread_local` storage class specifier is for:

```
void method()
{
     thread_local int var = 0;
     var++;
}
```

This means that each thread will have its own version of `var` which will be initialized on the first run through that function and destroyed on thread exit.

Comment: I think this answer would be much better if you'd go over (or at least link to) possible performance implications of using thread local storage.

Comment: @KubaOber: That's a different question.

Comment: Sure, just link to it if you happen to know about one or two with good answers :)

Answer (score 9):

You said, in a comment:

> I do want a variable that is specific for each instance of a class

That's precisely what an instance variable is (a.k.a. a per-instance member).

`static` members and function local variables are *not* specific to each instance of a class! They are either completely global (one instance per entire executable), or are per-thread if you use C++11 and declare them `thread_local`.

You absolutely need a member variable. That's the only way to guarantee that the variable will be specific for each instance of the class.

You might argue that you create a dedicated thread per each instance of the class. First of all, it's likely that you shouldn't be doing that. Secondly, if you ever change your mind, and stop creating a per-class thread and, say, use a thread pool instead, your code will instantly break.

So, the proper and straightforward thing is to have it as an instance variable (as opposed to a class variable):

```
// OK - instance variable
class C { int var; };

// WRONG - class variable and lookalikes
class C { static int var; };
class C { void foo() { static int var; } };

// WRONG - thread variable, but **not** instance variable
class C { static thread_local int var; };
class C { void foo() { static thread_local int var; } };
```

If you want, you can indicate your intent by including the method's name in the variable name:

```
class C {
  int foo_var;
  C() : foo_var(0) {}
  void foo() { ... }
};
```

Finally, if you're OK with a bit more typing, you can use a member wrapper to enforce the scope it's used in:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, typename Member, Member member>
class ScopedMember {
   T data;
public:
   explicit ScopedMember(const T & d) : data(d) {}
   explicit ScopedMember(T && d) : data(std::move(d)) {}
   ScopedMember() {}
   template <Member m, void(*)(char[member == m ? 1 : -1]) = (void(*)(char[1]))0>
   T & use() { return data; }
   template <Member m, void(*)(char[member == m ? 1 : -1]) = (void(*)(char[1]))0>
   const T & use() const { return data; }
};

class C {
public:
   C() : m_foo(-1) {}
   void granted() {
      auto & foo = m_foo.use<&C::granted>();
      foo = 5;
      assert(m_foo.use<&C::granted>() == 5);
   }
   void rejected() {
#if 0
      // Won't compile
      auto & foo = m_foo.use<&C::rejected>();
#endif
   }
private:
   ScopedMember<int, void(C::*)(), &C::granted> m_foo;
};

int main()
{
   C().granted();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I kind of agree here. Its to bad there are no "per instance" static variables just like "per thread" are. But I gues that would ruin the static definition wouldnt it?

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you want a variable to be different from thread to thread, that variable should not be static. It's looses the point of a static variable, which is, by definition, a variable that:

1. It's shared by all objects of that class.
2. It does not need an class instance (object) to be accessed.

The question you're asking it's not a "coding problem", but an architectural one. I don't know what kind of system/app you're developing, maybe you need to approach your problem in a different way.

Ask yourself this questions:

- Why do I need threads?
- Why do I need this variable to be static?
- What information do I need to share between threads and what information I don't want to share?

If you are more specific, maybe I can give you a more specific answer/approach.

Comment: Well, I do want a variable that is specific for each instance of a class (so thread as well). I also need it to be not local, because it is used in a method that is called in a for loop. I Could use a general member variable for that, but that variable is used only in that specific method so I dont need it outside. Thats why static for each thread.

Comment: So the answer given by @Pumkko is the best one you can get, although conceptually/theoretical wrong.

Comment: thread_local was only introduced in C++11, which means that your program has no retro-compatibility (which may or may not be an issue). But the main point here is that static variables are allocated on the call stack; objects are dynamically allocated in heap memory.

Check [static variables wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) and [thread local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) for more information

Comment: I read my answer I noted I didn't answer the question itself. So, simplifying: you want a static variable to have different values from object to object, which is exactly the opposite purpose of static member variables (they are shared by all objects of that class).

Comment: Yes but if it would be a member isnt that giving a variable to much scope? More than it needs? In this situation I need a local variable that doesnt reset after each time the method is called.

Comment: So you should make that variable a private member of that class. By making that, it's only accessible inside the class.

Comment: But it should be accesible only in one method of that class, not entire class.

Comment: So the main question here is: why do you have that restriction?

Comment: Its not a restriction- its just that this variable is used specifically only in that method. It is not needed anywhere else. So why show it?

Comment: If the member is private, you're not showing it. If you want to "save/store" its value from each time you run that function, that variable should not be local to that function. A variable being local in a function, means that after you finish the function, that variable is not longer needed and that you can free its memory.

Comment: class A{
    int var1 = 0;

    void myFunction1(){
       var1++;
    }

    void myFunction2(){
       int var2 = 0;
       var2++;
    }

    }

var1 is private, so only is accessible inside class A, but the value is kept (and incremented) everytime you run myFunction1.

var2 is local to myFunction2, so each time you run myFunction2, it'll start at 0 and increment to 1.

As far as I understood, you want the first one.

Comment: I want the variable to stay the same value each time the method using it is called. At the same time, I dont need the variable to be visible outside that method, because it is the only one using it.

Comment: There are two different concepts here that you're mixing: lifetime and scope.

The scope of variable is where the variable name can be seen. The lifetime of a variable is the period over which it exists. If var were defined without the keyword static, the lifetime would be from the entry into method() to the return from method(); 

The keyword static acts to extend the lifetime of a variable to the lifetime of the programme; e.g. initialization occurs once and once only and then the variable retains its value over all future calls to method().

Comment: I know how this works. Thats why I used this mechanism. I can achieve 2 thigs that i want: 1. Local scope 2. global lifetime.